# Changing title of wordpress RSS feed

Tags: rss

I need to change the title of the feed that appears in the top in `mywebsite.com/feed`. I have tried editing files in wp-includes and also have tried this code :

```
 function filter_wp_title_rss( $get_wp_title_rss, $deprecated ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return 'new title'; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'wp_title_rss', 'filter_wp_title_rss', 10, 2 );
```

But this does not work.

Comment: At first look this code looks OK. Maybe some plugin is overwriting your change? Check the filter priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *functions.php* of theme:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title_rss', 'my_rss_filter', 20, 1 );

function my_rss_filter( $rss_title ) {
    $rss_title = 'New Title';
    return $rss_title;
}
```

I added a lower priority of 20, and just ditched the deprecated stuff altogether.
You could just return a text string as you have it, of course, but I included the rest for a more complete reference.

Comment: This seems to change the title of all feeds.  e.g. I have a feed at /feed/podcast/ created by the Blubrry plugin, and this is changing its feed title too.